# Get number at the end of the filename in bash

Tags: bash, numbers

So, I'm making a script and I want to automatically get the number at the end of the filename while ignoring the rest of the file name. Here are some examples of filenames and what should be returned when the command specified is ran on them.

1. Name:`num71.gif` Result:`71`
2. Name:`file1_num62.jpg` Result:`62`
3. Name:`1_num3.png` Result:`3`
4. Name:`24_1024.gif` Result:`1024`
5. Name:`12806.png` Result:`12806`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using any regex you can use this function to get last number before extension:

```
fn() { declare local s="${1%%.*}"; echo "${s##*[!0-9]}"; }
```

Call it as:

```
$> fn '24_1024.gif'
1024
$> fn '12806.png'
12806
$> fn 'num71.gif'
71
$> fn '1_num3.png'
3
$> fn 'file1_num62.jpg'
62
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution (assuming the filename is in a variable) is to capture it using a regular expression:

```
[[ ${f%%.*} =~ [[:digit:]]+$ ]] && num=$BASH_REMATCH
```

The parameter expansion strips any extensions from the file name, so that we need only capture the longest suffix consisting of digits. `BASH_REMATCH` is an array whose first element is the part of the string that matched the regular expression; `$BASH_REMATCH` is equivalent to `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}`.

Answer (score 0):

When you want the last occuring number that might not be at the end of the filename, you can use

```
grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]+" <<< "${file}"| tail -1
```